# When I convert canvas to png, sometimes the image is full with black

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use `toDataUrl` to convert canvas to png, but sometimes the image is all black and with nothing else. Miraculously, there are times when the image displays the contents of the canvas normally. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
// "stage" is the class name of canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.stage');
const image = canvas.toDataUrl('image/png');
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = image;
link.download = 'balabala.png';
const event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
link.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Could it be because you are refreshing the canvas frequently using `setTimeout()` and at the moment you try to save it, it did not get a chance to draw everything?

Comment: Sounds like nothing has been drawn at the time you call this script. Could you show how it is called and the drawing part? Even though as a blind shot I'd say you wait for an image's onload before drawing, but not for exporting.

Comment: @Kaiido When I use 'toDataUrl()', the canvas has been drew.

Comment: And how? We need to see it in order to help you. Is it a 2d context a webgl one or a BitmapRenderer that has been initialised on this canvas?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the background of the canvas is transparent. Transparent PNGs in some editors (like MS Paint) appear with a black background. To remedy that, before drawing onto a canvas, fill it with a background colour:

```
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

So, if you're drawing with black on a transparent background, the image might appear completely black in some circumstances.

There might be other causes for this issue, of course, but this is one of them.